# series and limit in $\ell^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(v_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of $\ell^2$ space of complex sequences, such that $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{v_{n,m}}<\infty$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$ (as $v_{n,m}$ i mean the $m$th complex number in the $n$th sequence)
 and such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}v_n=v_0$ (in $\ell^2$ metric).

My question is: when is possible do this $lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{m=1}^\infty v_{n,m}} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} v_{n,m}$

Thanks so much.

Comment: These things look easier to me when you think of sequences as functions and summations as integrals. So here, you have for each $n$, $\int  v_n(m) dm < \infty$. and you have $v_n \to v_0$. Then you question becomes $\lim_n \int v_n(m) dm = \int \lim_n v_n(m) dm$.

Comment: I think that $v_{n,m}$ on the RHS of your last line should be $v_{0,m}$. I would edit but not before asking.

Comment: A corollary, considering the Answer below, is : If  a sequence $ (U_n)_n =((U_{n,m})_n$  in $l^1$ which converges  in the $ l^2$ norm to $U_0\in l^1,$  even if converging in the $l^2$ norm to a member of $  l^1 $  (like $  U_0),$   can still  fail to converge in the $l^1$ norm, because the sequence  $(\|U_n\|_1)_n$ can fail to converge.

Comment: @xavierm02 Not at all. It is the opposite : limit of integrals because easier if you think to them as sequences in Banach spaces.

Comment: Let $\varphi(v) = \sum_m v_m$. It is a unbounded linear operator $l^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ . If $v_n \to v$ in $l^2$ then a sufficient condition for $\varphi(v_n) \to \varphi(v)$ is that the sequence $u_n =v_n-v$ belong to some subspace $\text{span}((v_n)) =  E \subset l^2$ where $\varphi$ is bounded (since boundedness implies continuity for linear operators on normed spaces). Otherwise if $\varphi$ is unbounded on $E$ then it really depends on how $u_n \to 0$.

Comment: thanks to all of you.
@user1952009 you have spoken about my problem so i ask you: is the any hypothesis to get $\phi$ bounded ? is there a subspace of $\ell^2$ so $\phi$ i bounded?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

Consider:
$$\nu_{n,m}=\begin{cases}\frac1n&m<n\\ 0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
then:
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\nu_{n,m}=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac1n=1$$
Independantly of $n$. But:
$$\|\nu_n\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac1{n^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$
So $\nu_n\to0$ in $\ell^2$ norm, and
$$\sum_m^\infty\lim_{n}\nu_{n,m}\sum_m^\infty 0=0\neq1=\lim_{n}\sum_{m}^\infty\nu_{n,m}$$